# Utilizing max memory using strings

Tags: java, string, garbage-collection

Is there any way to utilize maximum memory of the system using `strings`?
I'm using `runtime` to display the free memory. I've tried with this code:

```
class Mem{
       public static void main(String[] args) {
              System.out.println(Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory());
              System.out.println(Runtime.getRuntime().totalMemory());
              System.out.println(Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory());
              String str=new String("Hi");
              for(long i=0;i<1000000;i++){
                     str+="aa";
                     //System.out.println(i);
              }      
              System.out.println(Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory());
       }
}
```

However, the `garbage collector` comes into action for every few iterations and frees up the memory. Is is possible to make it utilize maximum memory and display the free memory before `gc` frees it up?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the end, your string only contains 2 million characters. If you want to make your code run out of memory, change

```
        str += "aa";
```

to

```
        str += str;
```

That'll make the string grow exponentially, and no amount of garbage collection will help even with a modest number of iterations.

Comment: That should go faster indeed!

Comment: yeah, of course!! `str+=str` did it.why didn't i think of that?  But its hell lot slower than I thought. I included the try/catch block as suggested by assylias and caught the `OutOfMemoryException` even for as few iterations as 50!!

Answer (score 4):

A way to allocate and hold a large amount of memory quickly is to do

```
List<byte[]> bytes = new ArrayList<>();
for(int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
    bytes.add(new byte[10000000]); // 10 MB
```

Comment: Hehe, nice way to waste resources in a fragmented way, +1 from me.

Comment: you could catch the firsts OutOfMemory and reduce the size of the array geometrically to scratch the last bits ...

Comment: There arrays will go straight into tenured space continuously. i.e. there shouldn't be much fragmentation.

Comment: I see, then could a linked list be a better option ?

Answer (score 3):

`str+="aa";` creates a new string each time and reassigns `str` so the old string is eligible to garbage collection.

However it will run out of memory at some stage if you iterate enough.

You should put the for loop in a try/catch block, catch OutOfMemoryError and include your print statement in the catch block.

Answer (score 3):

try something like

```
    System.out.println(Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory());
    System.out.println(Runtime.getRuntime().totalMemory());
    System.out.println(Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory());
    String str = new String(new char[32_000_000]);
    System.out.println(Runtime.getRuntime().totalMemory());
    System.out.println(Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory());
```

note that `str += "aa"` is so slow that you may make wrong conclusions. GC cannot free no memory in your case